# Why does the_post_thumbnail output full sized images after activating post-thumbnails support?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I mean:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'thumbs_setup' );
function thumbs_setup() {
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}
```

My media settings are 150x150px on thumbnails, but now `the_post_thumbnail()` will output a full sized image instead. Why?

I see that the only way to have `the_post_thumbnail()` to really output the thumbnail size is to explicitly pass it:

`the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail')`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding support to 'post-thumbnails' also adds a new type of size: 'post-thumbnail'. But 'post-thumbnail' **is not** == 'thumb' or 'thumbnail', it's a new, different type.
Also, `the_post_thumbnail()` if called without params will output the 'post-thumbnail' size instead of the 'thumb' size.

'thumb' (or 'thumbnail') are setted via admin media panel, while 'post-thumbnail' is not.

Since the 'post-thumbnail' size is not yet setted, than `the_post_thumbnail()` doesn't really know what size to use, and thus it will output the full image.

To set the 'post-thumbnail' size you must use standard `add-image-size()` passing 'post-thumbnail' as the name, or, just use `set_post_thumbnail_size()`.

Answer (score 3):

[`the_post_thumbnail`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) is unfortunately named, because it suggests a small image but actually refers to the featured image of a post. Adding support for it simply makes the 'featured image' box available in your post editor.

Now, if you [look at the source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/), you see that if there is no size specified when calling `the_post_thumbnail`, the size is defined as `post-thumbnail`. However, this is not the name of the default thumbnail generated for every image, which is `thumbnail`. There is no image size called 'post-thumbnail' generated by default. As a result, WP will use the full image.

There are several ways to get around this, but the easiest would be to use a filter available in `get_the_post_thumbnail`, the function that is used by `the_post_thumbnail`. You can reroute the default call from 'post-thumbnail' to 'tumbnail' like this:

```
add_filter ('post_thumbnail_size','wpse275569_post_thumbnail_size');
function wpse275569_post_thumbnail_size ($size) {
  if ($size == 'post-thumbnail') $size = 'thumbnail';
  return $size;
  }
```